# Firebase Analytics doesn't work in real devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I followed the Android Studio assistant to o connect my app to Firebase Analytics, it's work fine in AVD and show the events in DebugView. But when i tried to run this app in my phone the DebugView dont get any events.

Testing another functions of Firebase(Real Time Database, Crashlytics and others), all works in both, real and AVD.

Code i use to active DebugView:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <my.app.package>
```

Code to receive log informations:

```
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Log of the app running in my phone:

```
08-21 11:00:07.240 V/FA      (15356): onActivityCreated
08-21 11:00:07.353 V/FA      (15356): App measurement collection enabled
08-21 11:00:07.363 V/FA      (15356): App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.papel.myapplication, 1:7809993896:android:1808a14c9e0b159897469d
08-21 11:00:07.365 I/FA      (15356): App measurement initialized, version: 31049
08-21 11:00:07.366 I/FA      (15356): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
08-21 11:00:07.366 I/FA      (15356): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
08-21 11:00:07.366 I/FA      (15356):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.papel.myapplication
08-21 11:00:07.366 D/FA      (15356): Debug-level message logging enabled
08-21 11:00:07.527 V/FA      (15356): Connecting to remote service
08-21 11:00:07.545 V/FA      (15356): Detected application was in foreground
08-21 11:00:07.554 V/FA      (15356): Session started, time: 607704075
08-21 11:00:07.608 V/FA      (15356): Connection attempt already in progress
08-21 11:00:07.619 I/FA      (15356): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
08-21 11:00:07.765 V/FA      (15356): Connection attempt already in progress
08-21 11:00:07.801 V/FA      (15356): Connection attempt already in progress
08-21 11:00:07.827 V/FA      (15356): Connection attempt already in progress
08-21 11:00:07.829 V/FA      (15356): Activity resumed, time: 607703994
08-21 11:00:07.952 V/FA      (15356): Connection attempt already in progress
08-21 11:00:07.956 V/FA      (15356): Connection attempt already in progress
08-21 11:00:08.083 D/FA      (15356): Connected to remote service
08-21 11:00:08.086 V/FA      (15356): Processing queued up service tasks: 7
08-21 11:00:08.203 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Setting user property: ga_session_number(_sno), 2
08-21 11:00:08.222 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Setting user property: ga_session_id(_sid), 1598018407
08-21 11:00:08.241 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Logging event: origin=auto,name=session_start(_s),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_session_id(_sid)=1598018407}]
08-21 11:00:09.004 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Next upload time is 0
08-21 11:00:09.004 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Unscheduling upload
08-21 11:00:09.010 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Background event processing time, ms: 769
08-21 11:00:09.032 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=7116014326966617553}]
08-21 11:00:09.808 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Next upload time is 0
08-21 11:00:09.808 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Unscheduling upload
08-21 11:00:09.810 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Background event processing time, ms: 779
08-21 11:00:09.826 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Saving default event parameters, appId, data size: com.papel.myapplication, 2
08-21 11:00:13.371 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Logging event: origin=app,name=app_open,params=Bundle[{item_name=Splash screen opened, ga_event_origin(_o)=app, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=7116014326966617553, item_id=7}]
08-21 11:00:14.163 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Next upload time is 0
08-21 11:00:14.163 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Unscheduling upload
08-21 11:00:14.165 V/FA-SVC  ( 4741): Background event processing time, ms: 796
```

MainActivity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        
        val mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
        
        findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener {

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Splash screen opened")
            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, bundle)
        }
    }
}
```

In the DebugView Screen only the AVD appear in "Debug Device".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

Analytics starts showing events when the app has 10 users.
There is a delay befor the events are shown.

Comment: The DebugView always show the events. He is make to test the events in develop time, without time and user restrictions. When i test this code in AVD i got results.